# Gist plugin on Sublime Text is too slow

Tags: gist

Gist plugin on Sublime Text is too slow. It takes several seconds(only 4 short snippets) to download all my gists to local and show them in Sublime Text. No way I could manage 100 snippets this way.

Is there any way to customize the code and use eager loading to download all my snippets to local? So that I can access all my local snippets and sync to gist.github.com when necessary.

https://github.com/condemil/Gist

Thanks!

- Nick

Comment: look through the settings

Comment: What do you mean? I think it is because the transfer is too slow.

Comment: well there is a setting in there which will only return starred gists. you might try to limit the # of gists returned to make it feel quicker. maybe there are other settings besides the "only return starred gists" setting which i found?